# Algorithm to move balls from one set of buckets to another set in least amount of moves given a machine that can move unlimited balls in one move

Tags: algorithms

One of my friends proposed a problem where you have n number of buckets (a, b, c, ..., n), each with a certain percentage of your total balls. You are then given a breakdown of how many balls each bucket should have by the end of the problem. You are also supplied a machine that, in one move, can move unlimited balls from a singular bucket to another singular bucket (ex. 10 balls from bucket A to bucket C). What algorithm would you use to ensure you always have the least number of moves possible?

I got stumped by this. It looks like it could be solved using an extension of Euclid's algorithm, but I'm altogether unsure as to how I would solve this. I tested the obvious answer of trying to match the 2 largest/perfect problem buckets with each other but that doesn't work. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? the minimal number of moves asymptotically, or exact? Also, I don't see how this problem is related to gcd, could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I have in mind a very elementary solution, which I'm pretty sure is optimal

Comment: @TheHolyJoker I tried a version of what saulspatz posted. My notes weren't the best as I was struggling with this along with another problem, so I could've misread my notes

Answer (score 1):

Say there are $n$ buckets, with $b_i$ balls in bucket $i$, $i=1,\dots,n$, and that the goal is to have $g_i$ balls in bucket $i$.  Call bucket $i$ deficient if $b_i<g_i$, excessive if $b_i>g_i$, and perfect if $B_i=g_i$.  Unless we are already in the goal state, we must have a deficient bucket $i$ and an excessive bucket $j$.  If the excess in bucket $j$ is $\geq$ the deficit in bucket $j$, we can move balls from bucket $j$ to bucket $i$ and make bucket $i$ perfect.  If the excess is less than the deficiency, we can move the entire excess, and make bucket $j$ perfect.

That is, and each step, we can reduce the number of imperfect buckets by $1$.  Since it is not possible to have exactly one imperfect bucket, $n-1$ steps are sufficient.

In the case where the goal is to have all the balls in bucket $1$, and each of the other bucket has at least one ball to begin with, $n-1$ steps are necessary, so this is the best possible result.

Comment: I was writing up the same strategy.  I suspect there are configurations where it will not be optimal, but you are right the best you can promise is $ n-1$

Comment: @RossMillikan I was just thinking about that.  Obviously, if there is an excess that is equal to a deficiency, we can reduce the number of imperfect buckets by $2$ in a single move.  The question is, if there is no such pair, can we create one by carefully planning the transfers?  Dynamic programming, maybe?

Comment: That's what I thought too, but that is not optimal for all cases as you pointed out. A simple case would be one where the buckets are as follows:  +1, +10, -1, -5, -5. This can easily be completed in 3 steps (A/C, B/D, B/E), yet can also be extended to 4 steps (B/C, B/D, B/E, A/E) without violating the rule of reducing the number of imperfect buckets by 1 for each step.

Comment: It is trivial to create an algorithm that guarantees the `n-1` worst case, the complexity comes in the non-trivial cases where optimizations beyond `n-1` exist

Comment: @saulspatz I think greedy algorithm will work as well